# .NET Nullable CS8619 Possible null reference assignment fix

Tags: .net-core, nullable, .net-6.0

I have a .NET6 project with nullable set to enable.. with that brings up this CS8619 issue with the following code. How would you go about handling this?

```
using System.Data;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Description",typeof(string));

dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
{
    // CS8619
    // Possible null reference assignment.
    dt.Columns["ID"]
};
```

This code worked fine in the old days, but obvisouly not with the column lookup being a DataColumn? type

Comment: I know I could do DataColumn pkcol = dt.Columns[dt.Columns.IndexOf(dt.Columns["Id"])];
then assign that to the array, but this seems like more work then needed to get around a null type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of Add.

```
var idColumn = dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
...

dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
{
    idColumn 
};
```

If you don't/can't do this and you know the value is definitely not null use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).

```
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
{
    dt.Columns["ID"]!
};
```

If you cannot guarantee it's not null than just check if it's null:

```
var primaryKeyColumn = dt.Columns["ID"];
if(primaryKeyColumn == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to find ID column");
}
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
{
     primaryKeyColumn
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that works but I forgot to add one thing to my example.. completely forgot this is in a data table that the schema is loaded from the result of a query which doesn't return what the primary key is.

Comment: So, then the nullable feature is doing exactly what is designed for… warning/preventing you from writing code that can result in a possible NRE.. what sort of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: What kind of answer? If there is a safe way to get a column reference for a known column... I know I can go through all the null checks, but I was hoping there was some type of built in method to do it that I didn't know about already for adding loaded columns to a primary key

Comment: What do you mean by safe way? What does safe means in this context?